# Tips on how I would find the transition matrix for the following phenomenon?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, matrices, markov-process

how would I go about finding the transition matrix for the following phenomenon (which can be modeled as a Markov process)?

Any hints or advice is appreciated!

During a study break, a student's evening habits vary from day to day:

- If he studies one night, there is a 20% probability that he will not study the following night.
- There is a 10% probability that he will not study for two nights in succession.

Comment: '-1' Doesn't mention the _effort, source_ and any thoughts.

Answer (score 1):

If we have 2 states:  S = Study, S' = No Study.

Then we can form a 2 X 2 matrix(pardon my drawing, I am new at this)

```
 S S'
```

S   .8    .2

S'  .9    .1

So the first row answers itself from your question.  The row S says our current state(night 1) the student is studying.  The column S says our next state(night 2) the student has an 80% chance of studying.  So column S'(night 2) must be 20% he won't study.

In the second part of your question we know if he does not study in the current state(night 1) that there is a 10% chance he does not study next state( night 2).

The rows must sum to 1(probability must add up to 1).  So there is a 90% if the student does not study in the current state(night 1), he will study in the next state(night 2)